# cpp suggest better ways to go to silence state without overhead/io calls

Tags: c++, daemon, cout

We have daemon that can be run at `silence mode` and `print mode` (print to std::cout). How to make it `silence` without overhead and io calls. Suggest more better ways to do so! Or write what is the way is better! (advantages/disadvantage)

eg:

**1 Way:**

Simple place at the code `std::cout << "blah-blah-blah: " << var << std::endl;` 
When need to go silence `close(STDOUT_FILENO)` or rewrite cout to `dev/null` (how?)

**2 Way**

Using `global bool FLAG_SILENCE` and check it before every cout calls: `if (!FLAG_SILENCE) std::cout << "blah-blah-blah: " << var << std::endl;`

**3 Way**
Predefined macros `#define SILENTCOUT std::cout` when need to be silence `#define SILENTCOUT SOMETHING` (something = some function that have operator `<<` and without overhard`(does not know how to realise, seems need to define our own function with defined`<<` that do nothing )

**4 Way** 
Predefined macro `#define SILENTCOUT(x) std::cout << x << std::endl` using `SILENTCOUT( "mess" )` -- dangerous, very ugly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common solution is to provide macros that enclose the `if` and the actual printing:

```
#define LOG( msg )                 \
    if ( !log_enabled ) {} else    \
        std::cout << msg;
```

Although in general the macros are a bit more complicated (for example, instead of testing `log_enabled` take a log level, compare it against a predefined level and log accordingly).

Some libraries use the option of a macro that returns a logger object that implements `operator<<` and depending on the configuration will provide either a proper logger or a no-op sink that just ignores the arguments. This might be slightly less performant as this requires at the very least the function calls to `operator<<`.

At any rate I suggest that you use a logging library, as these problems have already been resolved *many* times already.